# Изменение высоты UINavigationBar как в приложении Messages

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

Каким образом можно достичь того же эффекта, с изменением высоты UINavigationBar и "переползанием" заголовка, как в приложении Apple Messages?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

раздел Navigation Bar Titles:

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/navigation-bars/

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```